# MinGW perl system command converting switches to paths

Tags: perl, mingw, mingw-w64

I'm trying to make my perl prog portable across other perl installations.  Looks like <del>strawberry</del> MinGW perl is doing a conversion that is messing things up.

When I run a system command, it appears to be converting the window's switches to absolute paths.  I.e.

```
system('cmd /c "echo hello"');
```

gets executed as:

```
c:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe c:/ "echo hello"
```

That was taken from Process Explorer.

How do I stop this behaviour?

Comment: That's pretty awesome.  Do backslashes help in any way?  eg. `\\/c` in place of `/c`?

Comment: I cannot confirm this behavior.

Comment: @JoeZ, no, backslashes do not help.  No, I was wrong, I need 3 backslashes to get it to work properly.  But that's just messed up. :(

Comment: @SlavenRezic, so you made a file that contains only that line and ran perl on it without it doing what I said?  What version of perl are you using?  I'm using `v5.8.8 built for msys-64int`.  Miss typed version and corrected in question.

Comment: I tried with Strawberry Perl.

Comment: But with msys perl I can confirm this behavior.

Comment: No answer, but some insightful links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion