# How do I pass a literal forward slash into Node.js in Git Bash for Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, bash

I'm using Git Bash for Windows (as in, I right-click in some directory and select "Git Bash here" from the context menu). Node.js v5.10.1.

Here's my complete Node.js script, `example.js`:

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

Here's my command line and the output:

```
$ node example.js "https://example.com"
[ 'C:\\...\\node.exe',
  'C:\\...\\example.js',
  'https:\\example.com' ]
```

Notice how the input argument "https://example.com" has **two literal forward slashes**, but the resulting string "https:\\example.com" has **one literal backslash**.

I have found that no amount of backslash-escaping (e.g. "https:\\/example.com") or additional forward slashes (e.g. "https:////////example.com") in the command line can stop this from happening. The result is *always* one literal backslash.

Using the same Node.js executable to run the same script from an ordinary Windows `cmd.exe` window does not cause this behaviour. Running an equivalent Python script from Git Bash for Windows *also* does not cause this behaviour.

## Update

Watch this:

```
$ node.exe -e "console.log(process.argv)" "https://example.com"
[ 'C:\\...\\node.exe',
  'https://example.com' ]

$ node -e "console.log(process.argv)" "https://example.com"
[ 'C:\\...\\node.exe',
  'https:\\example.com' ]
```

Why does removing ".exe" from the end of the call cause the slashes to reverse? I am using NVM 1.1.0, if that is relevant. `which node.exe` and `which node` return identical results, both pointing to that EXE file. There is no separate file named `node` in that directory. This happens on both Node.js 5.10.1 and Node.js 6.0.0.

Comment: Just tested on Windows with node 6.0.0 and git bash. Nothing odd here: `node.exe -e 'console.log(process.argv)' 'http://example.com'`

Comment: I think this might be a problem with my environment. It's intermittent.

Comment: What happens when you run the command I provided?

Comment: It works okay. But I think `nvm use 6.0.0` followed by `nvm use 5.10.1` has made the problem go away entirely somehow. If I could, I'd hide this question until I know more.

Comment: It ssems to vary depending on whether I run `node.exe` or just `node`. I've updated the question to highlight this.

Comment: I think you found a "bug" (unexpected behavior) which you should address to the developers.

Comment: I do have the same behaviour using node 4.4.3 and git bash version 2.8.1.windows.1. Did you get any working solution or just stay with the workaround of using the windows cmd?

Comment: The workaround I found is to use `node.exe` at the Git Bash for Windows command line, instead of using `node`.

Comment: This is one of those posts where I'm so thankful I found it because it means I'm not going crazy.  Ran into this exact issue when trying to use `yarn` instead of `npm` for node package management.  The 'exe' suffix on the node.exe allows it to accept cmd line args with forward slashes when running under Git Bash

Comment: Got the same issue when using redis-cli and .sh scripts in git bash for windows. I was passing in an argument to redis-cli of "redis-cli set /keyvalue/stuff "myvalue", and then git bash would prepend c:\mygitdirectory to the /keyvalue/stuff when I viewed the output in redis-cli keys *.

Comment: This may apply to some http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line

Comment: Have you tried using single quotes (`'https://example.com'`)?

Answer (score 1):

Git Bash is based on MSYS2, which does a "[POSIX path conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion)" like MinGW does. This conversion windows-ifys paths with slashes when calling windows-looking executables. MSYS2 might have done some "Windows-looking" detection in a way different from MinGW.

The question joezen777 mentioned in comments points to [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386471/3770260): just add `;https:;http:` to `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL`. The documentation is available at https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Porting.

Comment: Thought that node was modifying the arguments - switching from Git Bash to PowerShell fixed it.