# Git bash is adding its current path to one of the parameter

Tags: git-bash

I am using Git bash in windows to run a `.sh` shell script. This script takes some arguments. One of those arguments is a path as shown below:

```
Test test --path /ROOT/phani123 --comment testing
```

When I debug the path argument through my Javacode it actually looks like `C:/Program Files/Git/ROOT/phani123`. Git bash is prepending its location to the path I've passed.

How to stop Git bash doing this?

Comment: Phani, any luck? i have the same issue

Comment: No.. may be it is how Git bash behaves in windows.

Comment: See here for possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line#34386471

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop MinGW and MSYS from mangling path names given at the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line)

Comment: The solution John proposes will likely work if you are using a recent version of git-bash, Phani.  (I recommend the latest version, 2.24.0 as of 2019-11-13).  So, I've flagged this question as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @John It doesn't work any longer.  And in my case the alternative solution of double-slash at the beginning is changing the value of an ID that starts with a forward slash.  Obviously it cannot be found.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the following environment variable to disable this:

```
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386471/8261

Comment: Bizarre that this question only got properly answered 7 years after being asked??? 
At least, it worked for me just now...

Answer (score 0):

Shamelessly copied from [the other thread with an MSYS focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65570275/5146586), for clarity here:
(Go and give the answer a +1)

In summary, to disable this Posix path convesion:

- For [MSYS2](https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Porting#filesystem-namespaces) (built-in): `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="*"`
- For [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/msys2-runtime/pull/11) (built-in): `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`
- For [MinGW.org](http://mingw.org) (with [msys-core-extended](https://github.com/sizious/msys-core-extended)): `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, suitable for single command lines, is slightly changing the argument so that it isn't covered by the rules anymore. This can be done by prepending `./` for relative (if there is such a use case) or `//` for absolute file names.

Your example should work this way:

```
Test test --path //ROOT/phani123 --comment testing
```

These double slashes go through to the application, but are usually handled transparently without problems