# Docker exec cannot execute script inside container

Tags: windows, bash, docker, docker-exec

I have bash script that performing some Docker commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Create and start database"
cd ../../database
cp -R ../../../scripts/db db/
docker build -t a_database:1 .
docker run --rm --name a_db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker -d -p 5432:5432 a_database:1
docker network connect --ip 172.23.0.5 a_network a_db
sleep 15

echo "Initialize database"
docker exec a_db /root/db/dev/init_db.sh

echo "Cleanup"
rm -rf db
```

On mac everything works fine, problem occurs when I try to start this script on windows machine. When I'm running it I receive an error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"C:/Program Files/Git/root/db/dev/init_db.sh\": stat C:/Program Files/Git/root/db/dev/init_db.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Directory and script (/root/db/dev/init_db.sh) exist inside docker container. I don't know why it tries to find script on host machine? Also when I perform command:

```
docker exec a_db /root/db/dev/init_db.sh
```

directly in command line (on windows) script is executed. Any idea what is wrong and why it's trying to use git ?

Comment: When and how do you run the script shown above (not init_db.sh but the script containing the docker exec command for init_db.sh)? Show the code please.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem... absolute paths with windows variables fixed mine:
$HOME/docker/...

Comment: Could you explain more precisely? I tried  
docker exec a_db $HOME/db/dev/init_db.sh
but received "OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"C:/Users/Igor/db/dev/init_db.sh\": stat C:/Users/Igor/db/dev/init_db.sh: no such file or directory": unknow"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to igaul answer I was able to run this on windows machine. There were two problems:

1. Path to script in docker container. 
    Instead of:

   ```
   docker exec a_db /root/db/dev/init_db.sh
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   docker exec a_db root/db/dev/init_db.sh
   ```
2. Line endings in init_db.sh. On windows machine after pulling repository from bitbucket line ending of init_db.sh was setup to CRLF what caused problem. I've added .gitattribute file to my repo and now init_db.sh file always has LF endings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug in Docker, but the way mingw handles these paths. Here is some more information about that "feature"; http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion. Prefixing the path with a double slash (//bin/bash) should prevent this, or you can set MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1, see [How to stop MinGW and MSYS from mangling path names given at the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line#34386471)