# Command aws logs create-export-task Error (InvalidParameterException) at logGroupName

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, mingw, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a bash script which i am trying to execute the

```
 aws logs create-export-task
```

command. The [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/create-export-task.html) creates a task in an s3 bucket and drop cloudwatch logs within a timestamp interval.

My script has also some variables like the log group name which is needed as an option parameter in the command

```
logGroup='/aws/lambda/lambda-name'
```

Then I pass it in the command:

```
createTaskLogs="aws logs create-export-task 
--log-group-name \"$logGroup\"  \
...

echo ${createTaskLogs}
eval ${createTaskLogs}
```

Plus with some other mandatories options.

The error i get is:

```
 An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateExportTask operation: 1 
validation error detected: Value 'C:/Program Files/Git/aws/lambda/lambda-name' at 'logGroupName' failed 
to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\.\-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+
```

As far as i understand bash is interpets the "/aws/lambda/lambda-name" value as a path and convert the first slash to local path C:// . 
Is there any way to avoid this in bash language or is a fault in the aws logs command ?

Thanks for the future help.

Comment: In what you posted, `logGroup` is not used at all.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with your bash script. Will you be able to share the script or the part from where `logGroup`  is defined till it's passed to the  `aws logs create-export-task`?

Comment: Hey guys i edit the full command i use . I am just calling the logGroup inside " " double quotes. Same response when i call them without double quotes. Thanks

Comment: can try with single quotes, `--log-group-name '/aws/lambda/lambda-name'`. If this does not help, then I think there maybe something wrong with your bash setup on windows, or full script.

Comment: Same behavior whith single quotes and also when i run only the command without the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with you using Git Bash to run the command. Mingw will convert POSIX paths that are used as arguments to Win32 paths. See [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion).

Prefixing the path with a double forward-slash at first and then back-slashes within double quotes("//aws\lambda\lambda-name") should prevent this, or you can set `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line#34386471).

Another solution would be to use a different shell like [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) or [Mobaxterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I tried changing the env variable but now i get a different error.
C:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe: can't open file '/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/aws': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I think its messing some othe paths. Also the double backslash didnt help... :(

Comment: Can you try "//aws\lambda\lambda-name" with double colons and backslashes?

Comment: Actually that was it . Thanks a lot. Very weird why that worked if you make it in an answer so i can close it . Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is put a backslash and not using quotes :

```
logGroup='\/aws/lambda/lambda-name'
createTaskLogs="aws logs create-export-task 
--log-group-name $logGroup  \
...
```

The backslash will prevent bash from interpeting the "/aws/lambda/lambda-name" value as a path and convert the first slash to local path C://

**Update**

Can you try this ?

```
aws2(){ MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 python C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/aws "$@"; }
aws2 logs create-export-task ...
```

Comment: For the purpose of investigation, can you type in the whole command in bash, without using eval ?

Comment: Yes i tried that too. Maybe something in my bash settings ?

Comment: I tried that now i get an error the log group doesnt exist so probably is taking different name with the 2 slashes.