# Python file writing is not working inside docker

Tags: python, docker

I'm a trying to dockerize a python script in which file writing of a text file and CSV file is there. but it is not working, the file is not getting generated.

For reference my code is

```
FROM python:3



ADD ./HMS.py /
ADD ./constants.py /
ADD ./Docker.py /
ADD ./SNT.py /
ADD ./Utility.py /


RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org docker
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org grepfunc
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org requests


CMD [ "python", "./HMS.py" ]
```

However, when I run the python script outside am able to generate the files. May I know why it is not getting generated inside the work directory.

## UPDATE

```
    def write_log(self, filename, message, type='info'):
        with open(filename, 'a') as log:
            log.write('\n' + message)

    def write_csv(self, filepath, data):
        with open(filepath, 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(data)
```

constant file contain the path

```
LOG_FILE='./snt_alarm_log.txt'
COMPONENT_NAME='SNT Alarm'
DB_FILE='./snt.csv'
```

Comment: What flags are you using to start the docker container? Can you paste your entire docker run command?

Comment: How are you running the container? What is the output? If `HMS.py` is simple, let's see it. Otherwise, try to reproduce the issue using a simple script that just writes a file. Also, I think you have some unnecessary `ADD` commands there.

Comment: @prithajnath docker run sntalarmdocker_snt

Comment: We will write some msg  and status into txt file and also in a CSV file

Comment: The output of HMS.py to the console is just UP or DOWN. But we are writing some message and status into the text file and CSV file

Comment: If the main goal of your process is to write files to the host filesystem, Docker's filesystem isolation and other setup might get in your way more than simplify things.  A Python virtual environment might be a better match, with tools like `pipenv` that can help set it up.

Comment: @DavidMaze But it is having deployment issues

Answer (score 4):

Containers are ephemeral by nature. If you want to retain files generated inside a container you need to mount your host file system to the file system of the container. There are many ways to mount a volume, but a common way is a bind mount

```
docker run -v /path/to/host:/project sntalarmdocker_snt
```

Whatever gets saved to `/project` will be visible in `/path/to/host` even after the container is killed

Comment: How to find the path to container ?

Comment: It is typically your `WORKDIR`, so in your case it will be `/project`. I updated the original post

Comment: But still am not able to get the files which need to generated by python

Comment: Actually sntalarmdocker_snt is a docker image not container

Comment: Even am not able the see log file too

Comment: It is working fine am able to see the output in the console

Comment: When run the image /path/to/host is still empty

Comment: I recommend shelling into the container and snooping  around. Try `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash -v /path/to/host:/project `. This should give you shell access to the running container. Then run your command `python HMS.py` and see if the desired file is getting generated in the container. If so then the file should exist in your host file system if the volume mount was successful

Comment: Is it possible to generate a file outside the container location

Comment: `Checking last update timestamp for ONT Log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./AMS.py", line 3, in <module>
    ONT()
  File "/ONT.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.build_test_case()
  File "/ONT.py", line 16, in build_test_case
    self.generate_log('Checking last update timestamp for ONT Log')
  File "/ONT.py", line 80, in generate_log
    self.util.write_log(constants.LOG_FILE,msg)
  File "/Utility.py", line 76, in write_log
    with open(filename, 'a') as log:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/edward/checker_docker/ont_alarm_log.txt'
`

Comment: Actually I need to read a file from outside the location of docker & write two files into outer location

Comment: Any file you need to read inside a container needs to be present inside the container. Is that error from inside the container? That path looks like it belongs in the host

Comment: I tried by keeping the file inside the docker image location and then it didn't raise any error. Is this file write not happened because of the base image as python. Do I need an another DockerFile for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Windows machine with a [Git bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) trying to follow [this tutorial](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/how-i-used-the-lxml-library-to-parse-xml-20x-faster-in-python). When I run this command to execute a Python script to write a file, I don't see the file in my local directory!

```
$ docker run --volume="/c/Users/nanders2/.python-xml-docker":/app pythonxml:latest
```

The issue is **with Git Bash's Posix path conversion** [as described here](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2204#issuecomment-638993192).

> This is due to Mingw/msys2 doing automatic path conversion; see
> http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion
>
> You can disable this by prefixing paths with // or setting the
> MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 environment variable (see
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34386471)
>
> Because this path conversion happens before docker receives the value,
> its not something we can fix in docker.

The **solution that works for me is to use [double-forward-slash in my path](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2204#issuecomment-919667137)**

```
$ docker run --volume="//c//Users//nanders2//.python-xml-docker":/app pythonxml:latest
```

Or I could use [Powershell](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2204#issuecomment-643648238) (i.e. stop using Git Bash) instead, but I don't like that solution.

Slightly better solution is to use Docker Desktop itself to run the container, and manually specify the volume/mount arguments.
[image: screenshot of Docker Desktop, go to the Images tab and click "Run" on an image to set the volume/mount options manually]

I started realizing the docker + Git Bash was struggling when it logged errors like this:

> docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Program Files/Git/app' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.