# What is container path in docker?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I'm trying to read a file from the host to the container which is python script. That script reads a file from the root folder.

For eg /a/b/c/log.txt(This is a dynamic file so I cant add this into Dockerfile)

I need to access this in the docker container. However, from this platform I got a hint that we need to volume.
`docker run -v /path/from/host:/path/to/container sntalarmdocker_snt`
*sntalarmdocker_snt is the name of image

The main thing is being confused about this *path/to/container*

1. Is it path were DockerFile exist
2. Is it /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/f901e49b67375d4b1105309569c92afae415309ac1787afa2a565a9c08708b18#

This question is related to [Python file writing is not working inside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62395031/python-file-writing-is-not-working-inside-docker)

May I know how can I resolve this issue. In short I need to read a file from host and write a file into host in which I cant add that in the docker file. Thanks in Advance for time & help

Answer (score 6):

`/path/to/container` is a poor choice of words. It is actually the path *within the container* where you would like to mount `/path/from/host`.

For example, if you had a directory on the host, `/home/edward/data`, and you wanted the contents of that directory to be available in the container at `/data`, you would use `-v /home/edward/data:/data`.

In the container's process, you can then read and/or write files in the `/data` directory and they will be read from/written to `/home/edward/data` on the host.

Bind mounts are explained in detail in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Comment: What should be the probable reason for not generating the files in docker when I run the image. But the same thing is generating when I run a python script

Comment: Who knows? There are way too many possibilities. If you want help, you'll need to create a minimal, reproducible example so that your problem is easy to spot. Create a python script that just writes a file, put it in a similar Dockerfile and run it. If you still have a problem, add all of that to your question.

Comment: Which propagation type(shared,slave,private,rshared,rslave,rprivate) should I use if I need to write a file into the host directory

Comment: $ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  -v "$(pwd)"/target:/read_app \
  -v "$(pwd)"/target:/write_app \
  nginx:latest

Comment: The default bind propagation works for most use cases. My _guess_ is that your program is a) not writing files for some reason or b) not writing them in the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

./path/to/container is the directory path  inside the container where you want your host's data to be bind mount  with container.

It can be any directory  path like /data ,/root/data etc. 
(/data does not need to already exist in the container) 
Whatever updates are taking place in the container's directory by read/write operation will be updated there in your host's path as well.

The only thing need to check is your host machine path to the specified folder/file
After bind mounting ,you can use exec -it command to enter into container interactive shell and then use ls to see the list of files/folders.

The path provided at time of bind mount can be seen there.