# databricks cli in git bash on windows returns error message invalid parameter

Tags: azure-devops, databricks, azure-databricks

I am building CI/CD for Azure Databricks, I have to build a python library and able to create the artifacts part of the ADO pipeline.

The first stage has below plugins

1. `Using python version 3.x`

   - with default selection
2. `Bash #`

   - selected inline option and set up below command

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel databricks-cli
```

3. `Configure Databricks`

Referred this [Documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=riserrad.azdo-databricks)

- configured the Workspace URL and the  Databrick token

4. `Bash #` with below command

```
# few other commands 
....
databricks workspace rm -r /MYPROJECT --profile AZDO
....
databricks workspace import_dir nb/artifact / --profile AZDO
```

Note: Databricks plugin by default configure the connection to profile AZDO.

Above displays below error, since I am using AgentPool with Windows VM, the git bash is being used by ADO release.

```
{ 'error_code': 'INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE',
2022-03-22T15:14:49.7904034Z   'message': "Path (C:/Program Files/Git/MYPROJECT) doesn't start with '/'"}
```

Any suggestion on why the /MYPROJECT is referring to the path C:/Program Files...?

Answer (score 8):

With little research, when using Windows and git, using  `//` it worked.

```
databricks workspace rm -r //MYPROJECT --profile AZDO
```

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250130/how-to-stop-mingw-and-msys-from-mangling-path-names-given-at-the-command-line/14189687#14189687)